# Can't find glew.h in Xcode 5.0

Tags: xcode, glew

I updated to Xcode 5.0 and I can't seem to be able to include the GL/glew.h file. In previous Xcode version one had to set the base SDK to current OSX, but that option is no longer available (at least I can't find).

The file glew.h is in /usr/include/GL and I already set the header search paths to /usr/include, but it still doesn't work.

Can anyone help?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it to work.

Find in the Project Build Settings > Search Paths > Always Search User Paths and set it to yes.

Also, I couldn't link with libGLEW so I had to go into the XCode.app and create a symbolic link to the the file.

```
Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/lib
```

It is definitely not a great solution but is a work-around for me.

Edit:

Here, I suppose that one is working with the Mac OSX 10.8 SKD. For other SDKS, the path should be another one.

In the terminal I created a link to my libGLEW.dylib (which was in /usr/lib) in this way

```
cd Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/lib

sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libGLEW.dylib libGLEW.dylib
```

Afterwards, back in XCode, in my project's "Build Settings" I set "Other Linker Flags" to -lGLEW

Comment: Can you provide the steps necessary? I have the same problem, added an alias in that location and my old projects are still broken :S, do you had to also link the headers?

Comment: The steps are in the original post's edit. My solution assumes that you are using a OSX 10.8 SDK, for other SKDs the path is different (another folder inside the SDKs folder). All I did to find the headers was to set the Always Search User Paths to yes.